# hex color transparency ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I would like to use some transparency code with hex codes colors, like here:
for example if I have black  and I want to make it 40% transparent I would use #66000000

how can I do this in ggplot so that I dont have to use `scale_alpha_manual`?

I give a example plot here:

```
data("iris")
head(iris)
ggplot(data=iris,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

For each color I would like to use the hexadecimal color coding for transparency. can I do it with `scale_color_manual`?
Thanks!

Comment: If you want the points to be transparent try `geom_point(alpha = 0.25)` or some other suitable value for `alpha`, adding `geom_smooth(... alpha = 0.25)` will make the confidence interval lighter gray.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use hex codes to control the alpha for the fill color, but you have the byte order wrong. In an 8-digit hex, the Red, Green, Blue and Alpha channels are specified by `"#RRGGBBAA"`, so black with 40% alpha would be `"#00000066"`. The value `"#66000000"` would be completely transparent shade of red.

If all you want is a combined color/alpha scale as suggested in the comments, try:

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(alpha = Species))
```

[image]

Comment: for each species I would like a different level of transparency, I tried with scale_alpha_manual but I get tow legens, One with the colours when using scale_color_manual, and one for the alpha values, while I would like one legend with colour and together their level of transparency..

Comment: @i.b see my update - is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, but I would like the colours of the species point coloured with hex colours using for each a level of transparency like here: https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4 but using scale_color_manual.. can I do it in R with ggplot?

Comment: In that case @i.b add `aes(alpha = Species)` inside `geom_point`